# I cant get text inside the button python using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`[html code][1]` it is a button which contains text I have tried like that:

````
###HTML CODE
<button class="secondary" type="button" disabled>Apply to sell</button>
###Xpath
info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='search-result']/div/kat-box/div/section[3]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/span[2]/kat-button/button") ```
````

I want to get text inside this button 'Apply to sell'
Have been trying to save another text and it works, but this button I cant get.
(I use `.text` on info later.)

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if before applying `.text` to info you actually get something? Why not use the xpath you get from right clicking the element -> Copy xpath and pasting it? The questions lacks too much information to give a precise answer, could you point us the url in which the button is showing up?

Comment: thats what i did i have copied xpath as you can see and .text i have used on my csv file to save the data which i get the from object info in my for loop which looks like this for i in something info[i].text and this method i have used before and it works.

Comment: problem is that text does not contain value, because usually it does have something like value = 'Apply to sell', so i could use one method and get it, but idk

Comment: Probably the item is not found. However you aren't copying the full xpath, could you try for this particular case (not in the loop) `find_element_by_xpath('full x_path').text` please? Are you able to share the url so I can take a look at it?

Comment: i have send imgur screenshot i cant send url, because you have to log in to see it

Comment: i have copied xpath tried fullXpath from both places and it didnt work(check screenshot). How can i get hltm code to print using selenium?I saw somone on java getting innerhltm

Comment: Ok, how about using a `find_element_by_css_selector('button.secondary')` ?

Comment: Yeah I usually use download it and then parse it using `BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source."html.parser")` followed by `.find_all()`. That could be another way of doing it

Comment: i will try it tomorrow